# Is there a simple proof that proves $C^1[0, 1]$ is $\Sigma^1_1$ in $C[0, 1]$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

In his book, "Descriptive Set Theory", Moschovakis states $C^1[0, 1]$ is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^1_1$ in $C[0, 1]$ in the exercise 1E.8.
Here, $C[0, 1]$ is the space (metrized by the sup norm) of continuous functions from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$  and $C^1[0, 1]$ is the set of continuously differentiable functions from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Anush Tserunyan says in [her lecture note](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~anush/Teaching_notes/dst_lectures.pdf) actually that $C^1[0, 1]$ is $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_3$ in $C[0, 1]$, that is stronger claim than Moschovakis'.
There is a proof of $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_3$-ness in Anush's note (Example 11.6).

But I think there may be a shorter proof of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^1_1$-ness than the proof of $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_3$-ness.
I suspect the following claim is true: for all $f \in C[0, 1]$,

$$
f \in C^1[0, 1] \iff (\exists g \in C[0, 1], \forall x \in [0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}, f'(x) = g(x)).
$$

But I have not be able to prove this claim.

Is the claim true? Or is there another proof of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^1_1$-ness?

Comment: I know nothing about descriptive set theory so can not comment on the second question, but your claim is false, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746525/is-there-any-function-continuous-in-r-and-differentiable-in-rational-numbers-w) question

Comment: Thank you. I did not know such an interesting function.

Comment: You can even make it everywhere differentiable. See Pompeiu's derivative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative

Answer (score 6):

Your claim is false, as pointed out in the comments. And clearly a function is $C^1$ iff $f-f(0)$ is in the image of the continuous operator $g \mapsto (x \mapsto \int_0^x g(t) dt) $, which gives an analytic definition. I don't think your question is suitable for this forum.

Comment: Thank you. This proof of $\Sigma^1_1$-ness is very simple and smart, which I have looked for.